# Angular17 deferred views. How can I escape @ symbol in template?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my template there is a static text, that contains email, like `email@domain.com`,
since in Angular recently were added deferred views, ti seems that the `@` symbol is considered like system character, and the parser blames that the template is invalid because of that.

Is there a proper way to escape that?

For now I just interpolate the email as a text, like `{{ 'email@domain.com' }}`

Comment: Your issue was raised here: [Multiple control flow issues: NG5002: Unclosed block "" #52082](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/52082)

Comment: Ok thanks. I have found that it replaces in the migration. `const REPLACEMENTS: Record<string, string> = {
  '@': '&#64;',
  '}': '&#125;',
};`, but I, personally prefer to use `&commat;` instead of `&#64;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `ng generate @angular/core:control-flow` to automatically convert your templates to the new templating syntax it updates all `@` to `&#64;`. So I guess that's the way to go.

Comment: So, you offer to replace the `@` symbol with its html entity code `&#64;`, but is there a way to escape it with any leading escape character? For example, like the `\ ` is escaped with `\ ` so it results in `\\ ` in *nix systems and other places

Answer (score 0):

## **Replace `@` with `&#64;`**

For example instead of this:

```
email@domain.com
```

You write this:

```
email&#64;domain.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative, you can put into quotes like `'@'`, because there is no escape character for that. I think it is more readeble than `&#64;`

Comment: this doesn't work, the @ symbol is still treated as a system character